# Reiniciar do método em loop while

Tags: c#, loop, while

Possuo um script para gerar certa quantidade de CPFs randômicos em um arquivo texto.

Ao executar o método que gera o CPF randômico dentro do `while`, o método é executado apenas uma vez e gera sempre o mesmo número no arquivo texto.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using geraCPF;

namespace geraTXT
{
    public class TXT
    {
        public CPF geraRand;

        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             CPF geraRand = new CPF();

            //Informa o caminho e o nome do arquivo apra o construtor StreamWriter
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\carol\Desktop\CPFs.txt");

            //Escreve linhas no arquivo .txt
            for (int i = 0;  i < 10; i++)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(geraRand.cpfRandomico());
            } 

            //Fecha o arquivo
            sw.Close();          
        }
    }
}
```

Resultado do script:

```
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
48307261058
```

O que falta fazer para que o método seja executado a cada incremento do `i++` no `while`, gerando assim um número diferente a cada vez?

Quero saber como executar novamente o método do início, a cada incremento, para gerar um número diferente.

Comment: Como executar novamente o método do início, a cada incremento, para gerar um número diferente?

Comment: Qual a implementação da classe `CPF` ? o `Random` é instanciado no construtor ou no `cpfRandomico` dessa classe ? Se for no `cpfRandomico` é exatamente o problema que o @Maniero linkou na pergunta duplicata.

Comment: @Isac, O Random estava sendo declarado como `var` dentro da classe `cpfRandomico`, daí o erro. Instanciei fora da classe e funcionou.